# On WordPress 4.4, how to get the post id using the comment_post hook

Tags: comments, hooks, actions

Since WordPress 4.4, it seems like it is no longer possible to use `get_the_ID()` or `the_ID()` when hooking onto the `comment_post` action.

How can I get the `post_id` when a new comment is saved?

Comment: for now this is the only solution I've found:

$comment = get_comment($comment_id);

$post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third parameter, `$commentdata` can be used to get the ID for the post that the comment was made on:

```
function wpse211367_comment( $comment_ID, $comment_approved, $commentdata ) {
    // The id for the post that the comment is related to is available
    // in the $commentdata array:
    $comment_post_id = $commentdata['comment_post_ID'];
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'wpse211367_comment', 10, 3 );
```

The `$commentdata` array:

```
Array
(
    [comment_post_ID] => 149
    [comment_author] => dave
    [comment_author_email] => email@domain.com
    [comment_author_url] => 
    [comment_content] => All work and no play makes Dave a dull boy.
    [comment_type] => 
    [comment_parent] => 0
    [user_ID] => 1
    [user_id] => 1
    [comment_author_IP] => ::1
    [comment_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
    [comment_date] => 2016-09-23 03:13:40
    [comment_date_gmt] => 2016-09-23 03:13:40
    [filtered] => 1
    [comment_approved] => 1
)
```